# Is it possible to differentiate a pop-up window from an application what share a windows process?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm wondering if there is any way to close a pop-up error, where the pop-up and the main application are the same windows process. The application I'm using periodically will give an error message in the form of a pop-up window. However, the pop-up window does not have its own windows process.

Is there any way (using powershell or batch, etc...) to kill just the pop-up window and let the application resume. Or, is it possible to detect if a pop-up has been created and simply kill the entire application?

My aim is to have a scheduled task periodically checking for these error pop-ups and clearing them so the application can resume it's tasks, which will same save someone having to log into an RDP and manual do clear it.

Cheers.

Comment: you mean error popups ? this is showed by call `ZwRaiseHardError` in your application. this make remote call to `csrss.exe` process, wich actually show messagebox. so this messagebox (pop-up) from `csrss.exe` process really

Comment: Depends on the titles of the window. If the window with the error-message has a distinct window-title of the main application this could be done. If not, I think it might get hard.